# How to download a Google Drive Spreadsheet into Talend

Tags: google-drive-api, talend

I'm currently having issues Downloading a Google drive file into Talend.

Im using the following steps:
tGoogleDriveConnection-->tGoogleDriveGet-->tLogRow

Note: Google drive connects fine with Talend. Where it fails is in the 'tGoogleDriveGet' step.

Please Advise.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: This is the error message that I'm getting:

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the help guide.

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide56EN/tGoogleDriveConnection

This is probably the best place for you to start. Also make sure you have enabled the APIs within the google drive settings.